# Allowing local admin rights

Tags: windows-10, administrator, windows-domain

We have a new laptop that is connected to our company-wide domain. Everytime something requires admin rights, it asks for a username and password. How do i enable local admin rights for this user on this single laptop? The laptop is running Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out how to do this. To allow local admin rights on a single machine, do the following.

1. Search for **Edit local users and groups**
2. Select **Groups > Administrators**
3. Click **Add**
4. Type the user and select **Check Names**
5. **Apply** and **ok**

Then restart your machine and it's good to go!

I have posted an answer incase someone else needs help with this.

Answer (score -2):

Our organization requires this for our tech support unit. The way we implemented it was to create a security group in Active Directory, added our tech support personnel to the SG, and then ensured (via Group Policy) that on the workstation the local Administrators group had as a member the domain tech support SG. This way, when we hire new techs (or if someone leaves), all that needs to be done is place the new employee in the appropriate domain SG, and he automatically has admin rights on the workstation. We also needed to do something similar for particular applications on particular workstations; in that case, we set things up so that members of the requisite domain SG were only granted the admin rights on workstations that were also members of the domain workstation SG set up for this application. Again, in order to accommodate personnel or equipment changes, all that needs to be done is update the requisite domain-level SGs.